# Making an array with arrays of different shapes

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have several data that are in arrays of shapes (ni, 4), where ni is the number of measurements I made for the i-th realization of the experiment. So, in other words, I have several arrays that have 4 columns but different numbers of rows. Let's say I performed the experiment M times, so there are M different values of ni.

I want to organize all this data in one big array A with shape (M) so that I can easily select which experiment I want to work with. If I want to use experiment number one I will use the array A[0], and so on.

I tried using numpy.stack, numpy.concatenate, numpy.append, numpy.insert but I cant manage to do this effectively. I always have a problem because the shapes are never the same, since ni takes different values for every experiment. How can I do this?

Note: I have many experiments, so I can't just do A = [E1, E2, E3, ..., EM].

Comment: Are the arrays all the same shape? If not, you probably don't want to use a numpy array

Comment: What's wrong with tbe `A` list?  `A[0]` works just fine, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid, I've searched for almost an hour and right after posting I find a solution. Apparently numpy.append is really bad for doing what I'm doing so what I should do is:

```
A = []

for i in range(1, M):
    A.append(Ei)    # Ei is the i-th experiment

A = np.asarray(A)
```

Is there any other way of solving this? I think this works for me though.